# Data storing inside dart class with const values

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to store some defualt data for my app inside a class with const values.
data is a list of items.
Is this a good idea or bad practice?
thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. You can create a dart class then have static const variables for your default data.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a class you can just create a .dart file with global values and then import it as e.g. `import 'constant.dart as constant'` and use the values with the prefix `constant.`

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two ways to achieve this.

- You can create a dart file with global values as mentioned above for example

  ```
  const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
  const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF000000);
  ```

or

- You create a dart class with static const variables for example

  ```
  class AppColors {
    const primaryColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
    const secondaryColor = Color(0xFF000000);
  }
  ```

The later is to group related default values.